# How can I pause a GCP Pubsub push subscription?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

For various reasons we have run into scenarios where we would like to "pause" push notifications from a Google Cloud Platform (GCP) Pubsub subscription and just allow them to queue up, and then eventually "unpause" and allow pushes to continue without losing any messages.

1. Is this a built in feature?
2. Can you suggest a workaround?

Comment: I'm not seeing it as a [pubsub api feature](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.subscriptions#PushConfig)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Good news. I stumbled upon the answer at https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/subscriber#receive_push

> Stopping/pausing and resuming push delivery
>
> To pause receiving messages for a subscription, send a
>   modifyPushConfigRequest to **set the push endpoint to an empty
>   string**. The messages will accumulate, but will not be delivered. To
>   resume receiving messages, send another modifyPushConfigRequest
>   request with a populated push endpoint.
>
> To permanently stop delivery, you should delete the subscription.

Comment: I just tried this and Google now technically doesn't allow an empty string. Using the CLI and specifying an empty string just switches the subscription to be "pull" instead of "push". I'm guessing it's also possible to make the same change in the portal. This appears to have the same effect though (pausing the subscription).

Answer (score 4):

There is no "pause" feature with push subscriptions. If you can, you might consider [switching to a pull subscription](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/subscriber#switching-between-push-and-pull-delivery). Then you can control exactly when you request messages.

If you can't switch to a pull subscription, you could just return an error response when you receive messages or make your endpoint unavailable. Google Cloud Pub/Sub will backoff redelivery of messages, waiting up to 10 seconds between attempts. It will try to redeliver messages for 7 days. Depending on how long you need to pause your message consumption, this might be a viable option.

If your not going to need to switch between "paused" and "unpaused" frequently, less than once per minute, then you can accomplish this behavior by switching your subscriber to a pull subscription (and not pulling) to get the pause behavior and then switching back to a push subscription to start receiving messages again.

Comment: What happens to the message after 7 days?

Comment: It will be deleted. Google Cloud Pub/Sub retains unacknowledged messages for seven days.

Comment: Thanks @KamalAboul-Hosn . I do see this in the documentation, but one thing that is not clear, is if the "retry" is per message or per subscription.  I believe it is per message, and that is one of the causes of our bill running up due to many retries and we get charged per API call.  1 million messages sitting in a queue, retrying every 10 seconds, adds up quickly.  We really need a "pause" feature, and it would also be nice to be able to configure the "retry policy".

Comment: The "retry" would be on a batch of messages whose size will likely be close to the size of the batches you generally publish. It is not the case that delivery will be reattempted on all 1 million messages every 10 seconds; only a very small subset would be retried. I have also added another suggestion that might get you what you need.

Comment: @KamalAboul-Hosn see my answer.  I tested it and it worked.

Comment: Yep, setting the push endpoint to an empty string is what converts your push subscription into a pull subscription!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's such a pause feature. Instead, you can use polling Consumers and you can stop polling when you need to pause. That's all I can think of.